# Converting list containing dataframes into one dataframe

Tags: r

I a list into one dataframe

```
# A tibble: 24 x 1
   series$seriesID $data               
   <chr>           <list>              
 1 LEU0254466800   <data.frame [9 × 6]>
 2 LEU0252881500   <data.frame [9 × 6]>
 3 LEU0252886200   <data.frame [9 × 6]>
 4 LEU0252886300   <data.frame [9 × 6]>
 5 LEU0252886400   <data.frame [9 × 6]>
 6 LEU0252886500   <data.frame [9 × 6]>
 7 LEU0252887000   <data.frame [9 × 6]>
 8 LEU0252887100   <data.frame [9 × 6]>
 9 LEU0252887600   <data.frame [9 × 6]>
10 LEU0252887700   <data.frame [9 × 6]>
# … with 14 more rows
```

To do proper analysis, I want to extract the data.frames stored in the second list element of the tibble. I do however need to know which table it came from, so I want to keep the connection to the  element.

I tried `unlist()` which makes a huge mess out of the data.

I know of a method from the dplyr package, where one can join tables and thereby creating a column keeping track of which table the rows came from.

I guess I need something like that.

I get one very long character and expect a table with a column indicating the subtables.

Comment: Try with `unnest`

Comment: Or `do.call(rbind, series)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually do something like

```
library(purrr)
df$data %>%
  map_df(~ .x)
```